# How can I resolve ERR_GENERIC_CLIENT in fastGet?

Tags: node.js, ssh2-sftp-client

I'm using ssh2-sftp-client 10.0.3 with node v18.16.1
I am connecting to two different sftp servers that each contain the same file. One is identified as "SSH-2.0-AWS_SFTP_1.1", the other as "SSH-2.0-MOVEit Transfer SFTP". When connecting to the first server, I successfully get the file with the fastGet command. When connecting to the second server, I get

> Error: fastGet->sftp: The handle value was invalid. Remote: sample.csv Local: sample.csv
> at SftpClient.fmtError (C:\sftpTest\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\src\index.js:87:22)
> at SftpClient.fastGet (C:\sftpTest\node_modules\ssh2-sftp-client\src\index.js:613:18)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async C:\sftpTest\sftpKeys\testSftp2.js:13:9 {
> code: 'ERR_GENERIC_CLIENT',
> custom: true
> }

Is there something I should include in the connect statement, e.g., the "algorithms" parameter? Does anyone know of any issues with MOVEit that require a special set up? This is how I currently have it set up:

```
sftp.connect({
  host: hostName,
  port: '22',
  username: userName,
  privateKey: ppk,
  debug: fnDebug
})
```

The debug output is long, so I won't initially post it, but if there's anything I should be looking for, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. MOVEit didn't support fastGet. When I switched to get, everything worked.